# Swing from 1994 to 2018 by town for MA governor?

Tags: united-states, election, statistics, governor, massachusetts

I was thinking about how Charlie Baker did worse in 2018 than Bill Weld in 1994. I believe that this had to do with partisanship and increased straight ticket voting.

I looked at county level data, and I saw that the swing was uneven. Like other New England states, Massachusetts has town level results. I want this so I could see how much each town swung. (The swing was towards the Democratic candidate from 1994 to 2018 statewide.) I am curious about what the swing between the two gubernatorial elections was. I suspect the swing towards the Democrats was larger in Democratic areas.

Is there data that could be made into a map showing the swing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Massachusetts has a very nice election statistics website which allows this data to be collated fairly easily. The 1994 gubernatorial election can be viewed by town [here](https://electionstats.state.ma.us/elections/view/96278/), and the 2018 election [here](https://electionstats.state.ma.us/elections/view/131501/). This, combined with a shapefile from the [Massachusetts Document Repository](https://docs.digital.mass.gov/dataset/massgis-data-community-boundaries-towns), allows us to create the following visualisation:

[image]

<sub>Zoom in to see town names!</sub>

Full data:

```
               Town  Dem % 1994  Dem % 2018  Dem Swing (pp)
   Mount Washington       17.46       48.45           30.99
           Egremont       31.83       61.41           29.58
             Alford       32.61       60.54           27.93
   Great Barrington       34.37       59.72           25.35
    New Marlborough       29.09       53.79           24.70
       Williamstown       35.83       59.36           23.54
           Lawrence       25.59       48.83           23.24
          Shelburne       27.07       49.32           22.24
        Northampton       41.79       63.79           22.00
           Ashfield       34.39       55.76           21.37
         Somerville       42.53       63.61           21.08
          Sheffield       28.21       49.26           21.05
   West Stockbridge       35.13       54.49           19.36
         Plainfield       33.60       52.91           19.31
        Easthampton       25.46       44.22           18.76
         Greenfield       26.21       44.92           18.71
           Buckland       25.50       44.16           18.66
           Brockton       26.11       44.30           18.19
        North Adams       29.57       46.77           17.20
       Provincetown       42.73       59.67           16.94
       Williamsburg       38.30       55.17           16.87
             Hawley       18.58       34.88           16.30
            Amherst       49.49       65.74           16.26
           Chilmark       37.53       53.75           16.22
        Springfield       26.17       42.29           16.11
         Sunderland       34.46       50.44           15.98
          Cambridge       48.72       64.60           15.87
           Monterey       43.58       59.28           15.70
            Chelsea       34.30       49.99           15.69
          Nantucket       26.51       41.62           15.11
           Randolph       29.40       44.09           14.69
             Pelham       45.34       59.73           14.39
            Colrain       27.13       41.49           14.36
       Chesterfield       21.57       35.77           14.20
          Arlington       35.82       49.84           14.02
        Bernardston       19.00       32.98           13.98
           Aquinnah       44.53       58.43           13.90
            Holyoke       26.81       40.62           13.80
          Wellfleet       32.29       46.00           13.72
              Acton       23.50       37.03           13.53
             Becket       30.71       44.22           13.51
              Truro       31.44       44.74           13.29
         Boxborough       20.17       33.33           13.16
         Charlemont       25.47       38.45           12.98
          New Salem       27.63       40.37           12.74
          Tyringham       32.04       44.44           12.40
            Lincoln       30.51       42.69           12.18
             Erving       21.01       33.18           12.17
           Carlisle       23.09       35.20           12.11
          Brookline       40.91       52.91           12.00
             Boston       37.62       49.49           11.87
            Wendell       50.14       61.89           11.74
          Watertown       35.65       47.22           11.57
          Edgartown       24.23       35.79           11.56
        Stockbridge       36.76       48.32           11.56
            Maynard       23.80       35.18           11.38
            Medford       32.00       43.27           11.27
         Clarksburg       23.84       34.97           11.12
               Stow       18.59       29.59           11.00
             Malden       32.66       43.56           10.89
            Harvard       25.03       35.91           10.88
           Leverett       55.72       66.55           10.83
           Montague       31.96       42.57           10.61
              Lenox       33.94       44.54           10.60
            Belmont       30.97       41.56           10.59
             Leyden       28.48       39.03           10.55
          Deerfield       28.80       39.28           10.47
            Waltham       26.61       37.00           10.38
            Tisbury       35.35       45.69           10.34
        Westborough       18.74       29.04           10.30
           Sherborn       18.42       28.61           10.18
          Princeton       15.48       25.58           10.10
            Sudbury       20.25       30.30           10.06
          Lexington       32.63       42.39            9.76
             Goshen       28.96       38.62            9.66
             Hadley       32.22       41.50            9.27
            Everett       31.77       40.91            9.15
              Salem       31.28       40.40            9.12
             Monroe       22.22       31.25            9.03
       West Tisbury       41.25       50.26            9.02
         Shutesbury       57.92       66.87            8.96
         Framingham       26.47       35.31            8.84
              Dover       14.22       23.05            8.82
         Northfield       28.65       37.47            8.82
             Berlin       17.16       25.97            8.81
          Worcester       29.28       38.08            8.81
             Bolton       18.17       26.96            8.79
            Whately       27.38       36.12            8.74
           Hamilton       16.17       24.64            8.47
        Worthington       30.83       39.30            8.47
            Wayland       25.57       33.81            8.24
            Concord       28.93       36.88            7.95
        New Bedford       33.78       41.67            7.89
               Peru       27.38       35.27            7.89
            Windsor       34.44       42.23            7.80
         Cummington       40.96       48.66            7.70
               Lynn       29.85       37.50            7.64
           Richmond       36.79       44.42            7.63
        Westhampton       25.04       32.67            7.63
       Northborough       17.07       24.68            7.60
           Hatfield       30.76       38.33            7.56
                Lee       31.37       38.91            7.54
         Longmeadow       17.07       24.55            7.48
       South Hadley       22.64       30.09            7.45
            Needham       25.43       32.65            7.22
        Marlborough       20.06       27.23            7.17
               Rowe       28.07       35.20            7.13
           Westford       17.35       24.41            7.06
          Littleton       20.59       27.64            7.05
            Orleans       21.19       28.23            7.05
          Granville       14.08       21.12            7.04
             Weston       19.67       26.67            7.00
          Wellesley       23.54       30.47            6.93
             Hudson       17.58       24.51            6.93
               Gill       34.10       40.78            6.68
             Paxton       15.39       22.05            6.66
       Southborough       19.38       26.01            6.63
            Bedford       24.37       30.94            6.57
             Groton       21.14       27.65            6.51
         Oak Bluffs       33.15       39.65            6.50
            Andover       18.82       25.32            6.50
              Essex       18.98       25.47            6.49
        Sandisfield       40.31       46.79            6.48
             Lowell       27.14       33.57            6.43
          Dunstable       14.57       20.96            6.38
             Newton       36.86       43.00            6.14
             Natick       25.90       32.02            6.12
            Melrose       27.02       33.07            6.06
            Boxford       13.65       19.44            5.79
             Sharon       28.57       34.35            5.78
         Manchester       20.27       25.98            5.70
            Ashland       22.55       28.21            5.66
             Holden       16.24       21.63            5.39
             Conway       40.94       46.33            5.38
           Amesbury       22.89       28.24            5.35
              Adams       34.83       40.02            5.19
         Pittsfield       39.50       44.68            5.18
       Lanesborough       33.64       38.80            5.17
          Attleboro       23.65       28.74            5.09
             Wenham       17.57       22.61            5.03
            Seekonk       21.87       26.90            5.03
            Warwick       35.91       40.91            5.00
             Orange       21.27       26.23            4.96
            Beverly       23.85       28.77            4.92
            Eastham       25.13       29.97            4.84
           Cheshire       32.21       37.04            4.83
        Southbridge       22.27       26.97            4.71
           Brewster       23.33       28.02            4.69
            Chatham       18.14       22.78            4.64
             Dalton       32.67       37.23            4.56
          Hopkinton       19.44       23.98            4.54
         Winchester       24.45       28.81            4.36
        New Ashford       34.07       38.40            4.33
         Chelmsford       18.52       22.84            4.32
             Revere       30.53       34.69            4.16
           Rehoboth       20.54       24.56            4.02
       West Newbury       20.27       24.23            3.96
               Ayer       23.22       27.17            3.95
          Holliston       22.07       26.00            3.93
 North Attleborough       19.24       22.96            3.72
            Florida       32.04       35.69            3.65
            Methuen       20.19       23.78            3.58
           Cohasset       18.93       22.50            3.57
          Haverhill       23.27       26.81            3.54
             Dedham       26.39       29.83            3.44
              Upton       18.45       21.87            3.42
               Avon       24.25       27.59            3.34
          Lunenburg       18.79       22.10            3.31
             Granby       20.75       24.05            3.30
          Stoughton       25.22       28.48            3.26
          Mansfield       21.18       24.37            3.19
            Ipswich       23.42       26.61            3.19
          Petersham       27.21       30.38            3.17
             Quincy       29.57       32.73            3.16
         Marblehead       21.61       24.74            3.13
            Norfolk       17.70       20.79            3.09
              Heath       36.30       39.35            3.05
           Westwood       20.99       23.97            2.97
            Newbury       20.82       23.72            2.91
          Dartmouth       25.99       28.91            2.91
           Medfield       19.30       22.19            2.90
      North Andover       18.97       21.84            2.87
            Grafton       20.53       23.38            2.86
   West Springfield       18.93       21.73            2.80
             Marion       21.39       24.18            2.79
         Sturbridge       17.94       20.67            2.73
           Sterling       15.57       18.28            2.71
         Washington       41.63       44.33            2.70
          Pepperell       18.38       21.07            2.69
           Boylston       17.29       19.94            2.64
           Rockport       27.46       29.98            2.52
       Mattapoisett       20.07       22.52            2.45
    East Longmeadow       16.37       18.79            2.43
          Topsfield       18.02       20.34            2.31
             Milton       30.01       32.23            2.22
             Mendon       17.21       19.43            2.22
            Hingham       21.04       23.23            2.19
             Easton       21.32       23.50            2.17
             Millis       20.83       23.00            2.17
            Clinton       23.16       25.25            2.09
        Belchertown       29.57       31.61            2.05
      West Boylston       17.14       19.16            2.03
         Gloucester       26.63       28.60            1.97
        Newburyport       26.94       28.90            1.96
          Lancaster       19.28       21.22            1.94
         Burlington       22.76       24.50            1.74
            Reading       22.64       24.28            1.64
            Duxbury       18.33       19.85            1.52
          Wilbraham       16.21       17.70            1.49
         Ashburnham       21.87       23.20            1.33
         Leominster       21.89       23.11            1.22
            Hampden       15.49       16.69            1.20
           Hinsdale       34.70       35.90            1.20
             Canton       24.44       25.64            1.19
            Shirley       23.11       24.18            1.07
          Rochester       19.69       20.71            1.01
        Middlefield       31.18       32.18            1.00
            Hancock       34.23       35.20            0.96
              Savoy       33.48       34.32            0.85
           Townsend       16.99       17.79            0.80
             Woburn       25.27       26.05            0.78
         Shrewsbury       21.26       22.01            0.75
        Southampton       22.19       22.86            0.66
            Harwich       22.69       23.34            0.65
           Merrimac       21.44       22.05            0.62
            Norwood       26.92       27.50            0.57
             Medway       21.26       21.82            0.56
            Norwell       18.88       19.42            0.54
      New Braintree       19.31       19.85            0.54
              Barre       22.89       23.43            0.54
           Holbrook       25.60       26.11            0.51
             Rowley       21.19       21.68            0.49
         Barnstable       22.91       23.31            0.39
   East Bridgewater       19.45       19.83            0.38
           Sandwich       21.65       21.95            0.30
           Plympton       21.01       21.28            0.28
          Billerica       22.05       22.20            0.15
          Fitchburg       26.77       26.89            0.12
         Brookfield       19.88       19.99            0.11
          Lynnfield       16.74       16.85            0.11
          Westfield       20.67       20.76            0.09
           Falmouth       27.97       28.01            0.04
           Abington       22.75       22.75           -0.00
           Chicopee       25.55       25.52           -0.03
      North Reading       19.29       19.23           -0.06
              Athol       21.48       21.35           -0.13
           Yarmouth       22.89       22.67           -0.22
           Scituate       22.96       22.69           -0.27
          Groveland       20.38       20.07           -0.31
   West Bridgewater       17.92       17.55           -0.37
           Charlton       16.83       16.44           -0.39
            Walpole       21.36       20.95           -0.41
        Bridgewater       22.06       21.62           -0.44
           Plymouth       22.50       22.06           -0.44
          Wakefield       26.14       25.59           -0.55
           Weymouth       26.86       26.26           -0.60
         Plainville       22.40       21.65           -0.75
            Rutland       19.24       18.48           -0.76
              Ashby       20.04       19.21           -0.82
             Dennis       22.90       21.86           -1.04
             Sutton       16.61       15.52           -1.09
           Hopedale       21.87       20.76           -1.11
            Gosnold       23.94       22.81           -1.14
          Braintree       25.75       24.57           -1.18
    West Brookfield       20.46       19.22           -1.25
             Nahant       27.29       25.99           -1.30
             Norton       24.22       22.88           -1.35
          Fairhaven       28.50       27.15           -1.36
         Wilmington       21.31       19.86           -1.45
         Georgetown       21.03       19.57           -1.46
            Halifax       21.97       20.41           -1.56
            Whitman       23.18       21.51           -1.66
            Russell       18.27       16.57           -1.70
         Montgomery       18.54       16.67           -1.87
          Salisbury       21.78       19.89           -1.89
             Agawam       19.60       17.70           -1.89
             Auburn       21.85       19.94           -1.91
               Hull       29.31       27.27           -2.03
            Danvers       22.34       20.21           -2.14
       Tyngsborough       20.19       18.04           -2.16
           Winthrop       28.31       25.76           -2.56
         Foxborough       25.02       22.43           -2.59
           Pembroke       22.54       19.93           -2.62
             Bourne       23.44       20.75           -2.69
           Stoneham       27.44       24.70           -2.74
             Hanson       22.05       19.29           -2.76
             Ludlow       23.34       20.51           -2.83
            Spencer       21.64       18.76           -2.87
            Wareham       27.27       24.35           -2.92
            Mashpee       24.27       21.29           -2.98
          Tewksbury       22.69       19.70           -2.99
            Hanover       20.34       17.33           -3.01
        Westminster       21.64       18.58           -3.07
        Hubbardston       21.74       18.64           -3.10
   North Brookfield       21.13       17.90           -3.23
             Dracut       21.66       18.39           -3.27
          Royalston       30.47       27.13           -3.34
           Franklin       25.62       22.01           -3.61
             Oxford       22.56       18.82           -3.73
          Brimfield       24.96       21.14           -3.82
            Milford       26.86       22.92           -3.94
         Bellingham       24.27       20.20           -4.06
          Leicester       22.50       18.39           -4.10
          Lakeville       22.37       18.25           -4.12
            Tolland       24.83       20.69           -4.14
          Southwick       20.27       16.12           -4.14
         Huntington       30.13       25.95           -4.18
           Rockland       25.37       21.17           -4.19
          Blandford       21.78       17.55           -4.23
           Uxbridge       24.37       20.10           -4.27
         Marshfield       24.87       20.50           -4.37
            Holland       24.14       19.72           -4.42
           Kingston       24.29       19.85           -4.45
             Oakham       21.92       17.45           -4.47
           Millbury       22.81       18.28           -4.53
      Middleborough       23.85       19.27           -4.57
             Saugus       25.84       21.24           -4.60
         Winchendon       24.13       19.48           -4.65
           Westport       33.10       28.15           -4.95
           Wrentham       24.24       19.28           -4.96
    East Brookfield       20.29       15.10           -5.19
             Carver       24.36       19.12           -5.24
         Swampscott       27.46       22.17           -5.28
          Middleton       22.03       16.65           -5.39
            Raynham       25.45       19.59           -5.86
           Acushnet       29.03       23.16           -5.88
            Douglas       22.24       16.34           -5.89
         Blackstone       26.63       20.57           -6.05
            Peabody       28.06       21.90           -6.15
            Webster       26.64       20.44           -6.20
             Dudley       24.14       17.62           -6.53
        Northbridge       22.89       16.36           -6.54
        Phillipston       26.95       19.91           -7.05
            Chester       26.60       19.30           -7.29
             Monson       27.65       20.24           -7.41
            Gardner       28.97       21.37           -7.60
             Warren       27.73       19.66           -8.07
           Freetown       28.66       20.21           -8.45
              Wales       28.10       19.06           -9.04
            Swansea       34.89       25.32           -9.56
            Berkley       31.59       21.90           -9.68
         Fall River       42.61       32.14          -10.46
             Palmer       31.42       20.73          -10.69
           Hardwick       33.13       22.17          -10.96
          Millville       30.84       19.51          -11.34
          Templeton       28.12       16.75          -11.37
            Taunton       38.76       27.16          -11.59
            Dighton       32.69       20.92          -11.77
               Ware       33.17       20.63          -12.54
           Somerset       38.71       25.97          -12.74
               Otis       51.22       36.77          -14.45
```